# Are there any helpers that permit handlebars bindings to be ignored / not compiled?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, handlebars.js, assemble

I'm using assemble with grunt to build handlebars templates, but I've got some areas that I don't want to be compiled, so that they can be rendered afterwards in the browser.

Are there any special tags/helpers that can do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can escape the handlebars so they're excluded during the assemble build, then use them in the frontend...

```
{{! rendered by assemble }}
<h1>{{foo}}</h1>

\{{! rendered on the browser }}
<h2>\{{bar}}</h2>
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Is there another way to do this on a larger scale than replacing each {{}} with \{{}}?